# Как настроить datepicker со сторонними зависимостями, используя Require JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, datepicker

[Оригинал.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244345/how-do-i-configure-a-date-picker-with-third-party-js-dependencies-using-require)

В моем приложении я пытаюсь использовать Date Range Picker: У меня получилось заставить это работать с помощью установки всех скриптов в секцию `head` на странице: Однако я не уверен как сделать тоже самое с помощью `Require JS` и сторонних зависимостей.

Для примера: чтобы использовать на странице `JQuery UI Date Picker` я делаю следущее:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui'
    }
});
```

Затем я инициализирую это таким образом:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], function ($) {
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
});
```

Однако, я не уверен как правильно настроить это, если у меня есть дополнительные сторонние библиотеки.

Конкретно в моем случае это moment.js and daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js

Вот полностью работающий пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyeqokno/1/):

Как настроить это используя Require JS?

Answer (score 1):

Ты должен посмотреть есть ли слово 'amd' внутри каждой библиотеки. Для примера: в библиотеке [momentjs](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js) на 9-ой строке можно увидеть следующий код:

```
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
```

Это значит что ты можешь включить эту библиотеку внутрь requirejs.config. Но если внутри библиотеки нет этого слова, тогда ты должен добавить эту библиотеку в shim внутри твоего конфига. Для твоего случая это будет так:

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui'
        "momentjs":"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"
        //shim
        "daterangepicker":"//tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker"
    },
    shim:{
        "daterangepicker":{
            deps:["jquery-ui","momentjs"]
        }
    }
}
```

Из-за того что  daterangepicker уже имеет jquery-ui как свою зависимость:

```
shim:{
    "daterangepicker":{
        deps:["jquery-ui","momentjs"]
    }
}
```

и jquery-ui уже имеет jquery как свою зависимость (10я строка):

```
define(["jquery"], factory);
```

То это значит что ты можешь включить **только** "jquery-ui" (без jquery) как зависимость для daterangepicker. Конечный результат будет:

app.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery',
        'jquery-ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui',
        momentjs: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment",
        //shim
        daterangepicker: "//tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-  daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker"
    },
    shim: {
        daterangepicker: {
            deps: ["jquery-ui", "momentjs"]
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery','daterangepicker','momentjs'], function    ($,dateRangePicker,momentjs) {
    //dateRangePicker will be undefined, but it's ok.
    window.moment = momentjs; //include momentjs in global scope because plugin wants it globally.
    $("#e2").daterangepicker({
        datepickerOptions: {
            numberOfMonths: 2
        }
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script data-main="app.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js">  </script>
        <input id="e2"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```